# Using Mathematica Resource Functions For NCBI Access

Tags: resourcefunction

In a very informative Wolfram Technology Conference video presentation [Bioinformatics in the Wolfram Language](https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=104&p=30&v=2407) by John Cassel he demonstrates code that makes use of ResourceFunction for retrieving data from the NCBI Entrez system.  However, copies of the notebook used in the presentation do not appear to be available.

In an effort to learn more about MMA Entities and Resources and how MMA can be used used to access gene data on non-human genes, I attempted to work through and execute those parts of the presentation that are visible on screen.  Unfortunately, it seems that the name of the Resource Function he uses for this purpose to call the resources that he refers to as "NCBI Entrez E-Utilities", within which several specific resource functions are called ("EInfoNBI", "EGQueryNCBI","ESearchNCBI",
"ESummary", "EFetchNCBI", and "ESpellNCBI") have been changed and do not appear in the listing of ResourceFunctions (https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository), at least not under those names. Consequently, this code no longer executes.

**Does anyone know the new names for these Resource Functions or the most recent modifications thereof, so that one can implement or mimic the code in the presentation, as well as have examples of the most current methods for this functionality and one can learn how to use and implement and potentially build such resource functions?**

I'm keen to learn more about how to build such Resource Functions so that I can similarly download FASTA files from the [BOLD mtDNA Barcoding Archive](http://www.boldsystems.org/index.php) related gene sequence databases, such as [GenBank](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genbank/), [European Nucleotide Archive](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/browser/home), [DNA Data Bank of Japan](https://www.ddbj.nig.ac.jp/index-e.html), [China National Genebank Database](https://db.cngb.org/), and [Zebrafish Information Network](https://zfin.org/) that makes use of COX1 (COI) mtDNA sequences and other genome sequence data.

Comment: The "NCBI Entrez E-Utilities" are a set of server-side tools developed by NCBI, rather than Mathematica resource functions (see: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25497/). The names of the functions you mention are almost identical to those of [the nine E-Utilities](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25497/#_chapter2_The_Nine_Eutilities_in_Brief_). Is it possible that the tutorial was using those instead?

Comment: Now that you draw my attention to them, it seems so.  At this stage of my understanding, its unclear how such calls to these utilities should be made via Mathematica.  From the presentation it looks as if some coding was done to execute these if so, but that was not presented.  Since I'm at a very early learning stage, with regard to resources, I'm unclear what those calls should look like.  At 8:38 in the presentation you will see eInfo = ResourceFunction["EInfoNCBI"].  Presumably, MMA executes this expression, since MMA must have done something first for this to work.  My question is What.

Comment: I see what you mean in the video. Unfortunately, those resource functions really do not show up in the repository anymore, so you may have to resort to contacting the video author and wolfram support.

Comment: Maybe you saw this already, but there is [an ImportFASTA function](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ImportFASTA/) to import genome sequences from NCBI.

Comment: Yes, it works using NCBI's EFetch and provides some hope in trying to figure out how to create the other server-side functions as ResourceFunction[] 's. Following MarcoB's comment, I've put in  a request to Wolfram and am waiting to see what thy say.  In the meantime, I'm reading about NCBI's utilities to try to figure out how to replicate the functions evidently used in the presentation. This approach is a simplification over the more complex approach presented in Mias (2018) that uses Jason and published 1 year before the development of the currently experimental ResourceFunction approach.

Comment: The difficulty with ImportFASTA is that one needs the NCBI ID reference in advance to call it.  This requires downloading and parsing a lot of text if whole records are downloaded.   Despite the simplicity of the ResourceFunction approach, it remains an "Experimental Function" and it's unclear what its fate will be going forward.